# Verb for putting laundry to the drying rack

Tags: word-choice, verbs, vocabulary

What verb can I use to describe the process of takind the laundry out of the washing maching and putting it on the drying rack? Is "I have to take out the laundry" correct? Can I use another verb instead?

As a non native speaker, I feel like I am describing the process instead of using the actual verb of it. I am asking because I feel that it is not the proper way to say it.

Comment: Is there a problem, for example did you try "take out the laundry" and someone didn't understand you?

Comment: @James as a non native speaker, I feel like I am describing the process instead of using the actual verb of it. I am asking because I feel that it is not the proper way to say it.

Comment: "Take out" definitely conveys the idea of removing the laundry from the washing machine, but it does not say what you did next - you could equally well have hung it to dry on the rack or put it in the dryer or just left it wet in a basket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple word to use would be to *hang* the laundry. Different people use different ways of drying, I'd say "Take the washing out the machine and hang it on the (washing) line"

Of course not everyone uses a line to dry clothes. You might "put it in the tumble drier" or "hang it on the radiator"

Comment: Or, slightly more fully, *hanging the laundry out to dry*.