# Verbs related to laundry

Tags: verbs, phrases

Closely related to [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162527/verb-for-putting-laundry-to-the-drying-rack), after clothes are dried out, what verbs are used for:

- collecting and putting them inside the house (maybe because it's raining)
- collecting, folding and putting them in a wardrobe.

(maybe something similar to make a bed)

Comment: [related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249925/116378)

Comment: For the second one - (ironing?), folding, putting away/hanging up.

Comment: If I knew of a single word for the whole process I would have supplied it. I suppose _putting away_ is the nearest.

Comment: @KateBunting  I think your comment answers the second one. for the first one is it comment to say "put the clothes in"

Comment: I would say _bring_ or _fetch the clothes in_ (which assumes that you are in the house and the clothes are drying outside). The link provided by Kevin012 suggests _take_. I wouldn't use _put_, as it suggests to me 'standing outside and placing the clothes in the house' rather than 'carrying them in'.

Comment: If you put your comments as an answer, I can mark it accepted.